# Is there a caution in Torah against leaning on sifrei kodesh

Tags: halacha, talmud-gemara, torah-study, jewish-books, derech-eretz-manners

BH

Is there a worry of leaning on sifrei kodesh like leaning your left elbow on the book while doing something else with your right hand?

Comment: https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Respecting_Holy_Books#Leaning_on_a_Sefer